# read text file and concat lines

Tags: file-io, ocaml

I have posted a few questions about file IO i'm just trying to find the right one for my needs, I have found and I also googled allot so I guess my final file IO questions is (you will see some pseudo code here):

```
let ic = open_in "myfile.txt" in
try
  while true do
    let line = input_line ic in
    line += "\n" + line
  done
with End_of_file -> close_in ic;

print_endline line;;
```

I have tried String.concat "\n" (line; line) clearly it's invalid but im unsure in this situation how I would use String.concat method.

Answer (score 4):

String concatenation is inadequate in this situation because `str1 ^ str2` takes time and memory linear in the sum of the sizes, so iterated concatenation would exhibit quadratic behavior -- you want to avoid that.

There are several solutions to your problem:

1. Use the [Buffer](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Buffer.html) module that was precisely designed to accumulate strings
2. Collect lines in a list of lines, and finally concatenate them all in one go with the efficient `String.concat : string -> string list -> string` function ([documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html#VALconcat)).
3. Use an existing library that does that for you. For example, [Batteries](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/) has the [input_all](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatPervasives.html#VALinput_all) function to get the whole content of an input channel into a file.

.

```
let read_file file =
  let ic = open_in file in
  let buf = Buffer.create (in_channel_length ic) in
  try
    while true do
      let line = input_line ic in
      Buffer.add_string buf line;
      Buffer.add_char buf '\n';
    done; assert false
  with End_of_file ->
    Buffer.contents buf
;;

let read_file file =
  let ic = open_in file in
  let lines = ref [] in
  try
    while true do
      let line = input_line ic in
      lines := line :: !lines
    done; assert false
  with End_of_file ->
    String.concat "\n" !lines

let test = read_file "blah.ml"
```